# openerp and rml

Tags: odoo

I am trying to use  keepWithNext="1" for para. I defined my para style 999. I am using it with the following lines

```
 <para style="999" >[[repeatIn(o.order_line,'line')]]   </para>
          <blockTable colWidths="530.0" style="Table4">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <para style="999" keepWithNext="1" >Detail Specifications</para>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </blockTable>
          <para style="999" keepWithNext="1" />
          <blockTable colWidths="98.0,12.0,420.0" style="Table5">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <para style="999" keepWithNext="1">Product </para>
              </td>
              <td>
                <para style="999">: </para>
              </td>
              <td>
                <para style="999">[[line.product_id.name_template]]</para>
              </td>
            </tr>
       </blockTable>
```

but my code breaks midway on two pages. Thanks in advance. I am doing this in openerp6.1

-Usha

Answer (score 0):

Why could you use the report designer module? Create report in `sxw` format and then convert it to rml using the  python script given in the `base_report_designer` module.